# A question on the statement of the Approximation Property for an ordered field $\mathbb F$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory, soft-question, definition

The source is : Junghenn, *A Course In Real Analysis* , CRC Press ( page 13) .

> Proposition $1.4.3$ Approximation Property
>
> Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of an ordered field $\mathbb F$
>
> If $sup A$ exists , then for each  $r\lt sup A$ , there exists $a\in A$ such that $r\lt a\leq sup A$.

My question is : does the proposition state the existence of such an element ***$r$ in $A$***, or only the existence of such an element in $\mathbb F$?

Note : I know that in case $r$ is in $A$, $r$ is also in $\mathbb F$ ( since $A\subseteq \mathbb F$) , but is $r$ necessarily in $A$?

[image]

Comment: We have $r\in\mathbb{F} $. And then $r$ may or may not be in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  an ordered field is totally ordered.  So a nonempty subset $A$ either has a maximum element or it doesn't.  If it does have a maximum element, that's the supremum and that's the element $a$ in question.

If you don't have a maximum, it's saying you can always find something bigger...which is the definition of not having a maximum!